# Character Counting in a String - C program

Tags: c, string, loops

I have written a C program. It's a character counting program. I will give input as below

Input:    `ABCAPPPRC`
And need as output:   `A2B1C2P3R1`.

But it gives output as `A2B1C2A1P3P2P1R1C1`. It basically doing as per the logic I have written in program. But I don't want to count the characters of string which have already been counted. Can you suggest what logic I should implement for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char str[30]= "ABCAPPPRC";
        char strOutPut[60]="";
        char *ptr= &str, *ptr2=&str;
        char ch='A';
        int count=0;
        puts(str);

        while (*ptr !=NULL)
        {
                count =0;
                ch = *ptr;
                while (*ptr2!= NULL)
                {
                        if (*ptr2 == ch) count++;
                        ptr2++;
                }
                printf("%c%d",*ptr, count);
                ptr++;
                ptr2 = ptr;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use SMS-ese in your questions (or answers, or comments).  It is a 'program', not a 'pgm', for example.

Comment: There are other things you need to consider for a proper solution. Should it be case-sensitive? Does the string consist of only ASCII characters?

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate the counting from the printing.

1. The first loop goes through the input and counts the number of occurrences of each character, storing the counts in an array indexed by the character code.
2. The second loop goes through the array of counts and prints the character corresponding to a non-zero count followed by that count.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "ABCAPPPRC";
    int counts[256] = { 0 };

    puts(str);

    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
        counts[(unsigned char)*ptr]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (counts[i] != 0)
            printf("%c%d", i, counts[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}
```

Sample output:

```
ABCAPPPRC
A2B1C2P3R1
```

---

> I could not understand the first `for` loop. Could you please explain it?

The `for` control line steps through the string `str` one character at a time.  It is the `for` loop equivalent of the outer `while` loop in your original code.

```
char *ptr = str;
...
while (*ptr != '\0')
{
    ...
    ptr++;
}
```

The body of the loop converts `*ptr` (a plain `char`) into an `unsigned char` (so that it is guaranteed to be positive), and then uses that value as an index into the array `counts`.  Thus, for example, on the first iteration, `A` is mapped to 65, and `counts[65]` is incremented.  Thus, for each character code, the loop increments the count corresponding to that character code each time the character is encountered in the string.

The second loop then picks out the non-zero counts, printing the character code as a character followed by its count.

(Incidentally, you should have been getting a compilation warning from the original `char *ptr = &str` about a type mismatch between `char *` and `char (*)[30]`.  Learn when to put ampersands in front of array names — you seldom do it unless there is also a subscript after the array name.  Thus, `&array` is usually — but not always — wrong; by contrast, `&array[0]` is very often valid.  Also note that on some machines, `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` and this elicits a warning when you compare it to a plain `char`, as you did with `while (*ptr != NULL)`.  You should compare characters to `'\0'` as in my rewrite; you should reserve `NULL` for use with pointers.)

Comment: Would you use the same approach when `CHAR_BIT != 8`?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: If `CHAR_BIT == 9` or `CHAR_BIT == 16`, yes (with suitable adjustments to the code).  If `CHAR_BIT == 32` or larger — then no.  Which platform did you have in mind, and what value of `CHAR_BIT` does it have?  I'm assuming that it is a single byte code set such as ISO 8859-15 or CP1252 rather than a multibyte code set such as UTF-8.  But there's a lot of work to do to handle a multibyte code set; likewise, there are considerable changes needed to handle a wide character code set (UTF-16 or UTF-32, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir I could not understand the first for loop. Could you please explain it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I intended for an answer like the one you gave me. +1

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in your answer, and that a simple way to handle that would be to define a set of characters and loop through counting only characters from that set.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour But that will cause an extra memory with extra loop, which is not required.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode Not necessarily. You'd be surprised at the complexity of the optimisations your compiler can make.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You used the ASCII table smartly here. But here comes a new program in my mind. what if my `Input : I love you I hate you` and output required as ` I 2 love 1 you 2 hate 1`.

Comment: Use an assosciative array for that.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: If you need to count words, then you'd use an associative array as suggested by [undefinedbehaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1989425/undefined-behaviour).  You'd probably use some variant of an associative array if you had to deal with full Unicode, too.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is alerady a character pointer, so when you do this: `char *ptr= &str` you convert a pointer to pointer to character to a `char*`. Loose the ampersand(`&`).

Also in the inner cycle you should check if the given value of `ch` has already been processed. In the case you use when ptr is pointing to the second `A` you should just continue, because you have already added the number of `A`-s in the answer.

Your solution is far from optimal. I strongly suggest you lookup **counting sort**. It will make your solution faster but also will make it simpler.

Comment: I'm of the belief that prior to learning about operations, one should learn about the types that C offers... and this comment offers that information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

@ Jonathan your solution is correct only when string characters are given in ascending order like ABCDEF, but it gives problem when character order is changed. Input string is "ABAPPPRCC" and required output is A2B1P3R1C2.
Here in this case your solution will change out put to A2B1C2P3R1.

Below program gives character count without changing string formation.

```
char *str= "ABAPPPRCC";
    char strOutPut[30]="";
    char *ptr = str, *ptr2 = str;  
    char ch='A';
    int count=0, i = 0 , total_print = 0;
    puts(str);

    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
            count =0;
            ch = *ptr;
            while (*ptr2!= '\0')
            {
                    if (*ptr2 == ch) count++;
                    ptr2++;
            }
            for( i = 0; i < total_print ; i++ )
            {
                if ( ch == strOutPut[i] )
                {
                     i =  total_print + 1;
                       break;
                }
            }  

            if( i <= total_print )
            {
                    printf("%c%d",*ptr, count);
                    strOutPut[total_print++] = ch;
            }
            ptr++;
            ptr2 = ptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    const char noncountchar = '\x11';
    char str[30]= "ABCAPPPRC";
    char strOutPut[60]="";
    char *ptr, *ptr2;
    char ch;
    int count=0, len=0;
    puts(str);

    for(ptr=str;ch=*ptr;++ptr){
        if(ch == noncountchar) continue;
        count =1;
        for(ptr2=ptr+1;*ptr2;++ptr2){
            if (*ptr2 == ch){
                *ptr2 = noncountchar;
                ++count;
            }
        }
        len += sprintf(strOutPut+len, "%c%d", *ptr, count);
    }
    printf("%s", strOutPut);
    return 0;
}
```